# Getting exception when we got out of system time zones

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I am getting exception when i convert current time with out of our system time zones. For example, In my PC all time zones are in UTC time zones. But when i get GMT Timezone(Greenwich Mean Time), It's not possible to get zone current time. Currently i am using below code.

```
DateTime time = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(DateTime.Now, TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id, "Greenwich Mean Time");
```

The above code throws an error as "The time zone ID 'Greenwich Mean Time' was not found on the local computer"
How can solve this?
Please help me.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Could try TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones to see what timezones you have on your system, think GMT might be "GMT Standard Time" but that method will get a list of all installed

Comment: there's no built-in way to do a 1:1 conversion. ou will have to resort to using 3rd party libraries like Noda Time

Comment: Thanks for reply  RoguePlanetoid, I tried with above method and i am getting only UTC timezones. Not getting GMT related timezones.

Answer (score 0):

The 3th parameter you're passing to "ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId" is a time zone name (I think) - you need to pass the time zone **ID**

The time zone ID you're looking for is "GMT Standard Time".